# Photoshop Typing Issue

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typesetting

Photoshop changes the place during typing. When I try to type ”17. March 2014”, it write "March 2014 .17"

I can't explain well, so I made a video. http://monosaal.com/wtf.mov

Does somebody know how I get Photoshop back to normal? I uninstalled and installed it back, but it still doesn't work.

---

SOLVED THE ISSUE

I talked to the tech support and I set my Photoshop back to default settings.

Find the Photoshop Settings folder in ~/library/Preferences and then rename it. Open Photoshop and everything is set to default.

Comment: That is in Photoshop? There must be something odd in your default date-settings; have you checked preferences?

Comment: You can answer your own question in the answer-field and accept your own answer. This would be good for everyone.

Comment: I have to wait 8 hours till I can do that. I'll be back in the morning to do so.

Answer (score 4):

This is really more of a tech support question, but you tickled my inner geek and I got interested.

I don't know how you got there, but what you're running into is that Photoshop thinks you're typing in a right-to-left language, such as Arabic or Hebrew. Perhaps you used some RTL text elsewhere in the document. I was able to reproduce the problem by creating a new document, switching the language (at the bottom of the Character Panel_) to Arabic, and choosing "Reset Paragraph" from the Paragraph Panel flyout. It's easy to forget that so many of Photoshop's panel options are "sticky," and must be reset manually.

Change Photoshop's language settings back to German, and you won't have the issue.

Comment: Wow - cool, I do not think I would ever have thought in that direction!

Comment: It was the video that tipped me off: the cursor stays on the left the whole time. That got me curious. :)

Comment: I noticed that too, but I doubt I would have ever thought that way anyway. Good stuff.